# Kubernetes nginx ingress unexpected error storing fake SSL Cert: could not create PEM certificate file

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, containerd

I have installed nignx ingress helm chat on CentOS 8 Kubernetes 1.17 with containerd, ingress pod failed with below error message. Same helm chat worked on CentOS 7 with Docker.

```
I0116 04:17:06.624547       8 flags.go:205] Watching for Ingress class: nginx
W0116 04:17:06.624803       8 flags.go:250] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
W0116 04:17:06.624844       8 client_config.go:543] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       0.27.1
  Build:         git-1257ded99
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.17.7

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I0116 04:17:06.624968       8 main.go:194] Creating API client for https://10.224.0.1:443
I0116 04:17:06.630907       8 main.go:238] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.17 (v1.17.0) - git (clean) commit 70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf - platform linux/amd64
I0116 04:17:06.633567       8 main.go:91] Validated nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-default-backend as the default backend.
F0116 04:17:06.843785       8 ssl.go:389] unexpected error storing fake SSL Cert: could not create PEM certificate file /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem: open /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem: permission denied
```

if I remove this from deployment, ingress pod is starting.

```
 capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            drop:
            - ALL
```

I like to understand why same helm chart failing on containerd

```
containerd --version
containerd github.com/containerd/containerd 1.2.0
```

adding deployment.

```
containers:     
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-default-backend
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-ssl-certificate=nginx-ingress/ingress-tls
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.27.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: nginx-ingress-controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
             drop:
            - ALL
          runAsUser: 101
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: nginx-ingress
```

**error message**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
W0116 16:02:30.074390       8 queue.go:130] requeuing nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller, err
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: exit status 1
nginx: the configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg613392629 syntax is ok
2020/01/16 16:02:30 [emerg] 103#103: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg613392629 test failed
```

Comment: nginx deployment yaml

Comment: Are you saying the same yaml works if you docker as CRI and does not work if you use containerd as CRI  ? You want to run it on containerd? Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 9):

I experienced the same.  the solution is not to remove the capability section but to change the runAsuser

if you download the new release (0.27.1) deployment of the Nginx ingress controller, you can see:

```
       securityContext:
         allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
         capabilities:
           drop:
             - ALL
           add:
             - NET_BIND_SERVICE
         # www-data -> 101
         runAsUser: 101
```

The "runAsUser" line has a different user id. the user id in my old deployment was different so I got this error. Since I Changed the runAsUser to ID 101, the id in the kubernetes definitions is the same as the ID used in the new Nginx image and it works again :)

Comment: yes, i am using `0.27.1` changing to 101 is not working. let me update my deployment yaml

Comment: I Was using 0.25.1 with runAsuser 33, with version 0.27.1 I needed indeed to update it to 101, thanks !